# How to use this generalised 'generating function' for the Gegenbauer polynomials

Tags: generating-functions, hypergeometric-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

[Cohl (2011)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.2735.pdf) gives a generalisation of the standard generating function for the Gegenbauer polynomials $C_n^\mu(x)$:

$(1 -2tx + t^2)^{-\nu} = A_{\mu,\nu} \frac{(1-t^2)^{-\nu+\mu+1/2}}{t^{\mu+1/2}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+\mu) \: Q^{\nu-\mu-1/2}_{n+\mu-1/2}\left(\frac{1+t^2}{2t}\right) \: C^{\mu}_n(x)$,

where $Q^\mu_\nu(x)$ are associated Legendre functions of the second kind, and $A_{\mu,\nu} = \frac{\Gamma(\mu) e^{i\pi(\mu-\nu+1/2)}}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(\nu)}$.

The traditional form is recovered when $\nu=\mu$, thanks to the simple closed-form of $Q^{1/2}_\mu(x)$.

This is certainly not an 'ordinary' generating function, as the polynomials are not simply summed against monomials $t^n$. How does one 'use' this generating function in practice? For example, how would one extract the $n$-th polynomial, or prove the Gegenbauer polynomial recursion relation, etc.?

This generalised form is useful to me because the free parameter $\nu$ enables a certain integral over a set of functions (where the $n$-th function depends in some way on the $n$-th Gegenbauer polynomial) to be performed, but the unusual form of this generating function is preventing me from getting a result 'out the other end' as it were, as I cannot simply match terms according to the power of $t$.

I note that taking $t \to 0$ and using [DLMF 14.8.15](http://dlmf.nist.gov/14.8) produces the 'correct' powers of $t$ (i.e. $t^n$ appears), but I believe it would be invalid to interchange the derivatives and limits in order to extract a particular polynomial from the series.

Comment: It is actually permissible to differentiate asymptotic series (in your case, asymptotic in the $t\to 0$ limit) "term by term", as long as the asymptotic series is actually approximating a function in some complex conical sector (with vertex at $t=0$) where the function is holomorphic. See for instance the remark at the end of [DLMF §2.1(ii)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.1.ii).